# MySQL table with indexes: do many inserts/updates influence performance? If yes, how to speed it up again?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

The question was, if you have an index on some fields in your table, if after a lot of inserts (or updates) the performance is affected and if there is some way to speed it up again?

I am not sure, but I have read so many articles about boosting performance that I got confused a little bit. Does fragmentation, e.g. apply to this issue? Or sth else? Or do many inserts on a table with a few indexes not influence the performance at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are probably looking for `OPTIMIZE table;`.

See here in the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called index maintenance, see also this topic: [Index Maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948553/index-maintenance)